# How would I handle a fatal error while setting up Calendar API on PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, guzzle

Following the Google Calendar API quickstart for PHP, I've followed the steps but, got the verification code and instead of getting the expected output " No upcoming events found " I get a

[image: fatal error]

No idea how to move forward from here...

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include your code [example] and any error messages you are getting.   Do not include pictures of code or error messages please include the actual text.

Comment: You have a null exception there is no way we can help you with that without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I've encountered this very same error with numerous WP plugins that had been developed before PHP 5.6 and where programmers have been, well, lazy. Once these plugins get upgraded to PHP 7, exceptions are thrown for things that were mere deprecation warnings a few years ago.

From what I see in your logs, you have a dependency somewhere on Guzzle. According to Guzzle's own documentation, the recent versions [require PHP 7.2.5 to work](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html#requirements). Therefore, I can only assume that you are:

- using a plugin or something similar that is based on an outdated version of Guzzle *or* you're using Guzzle yourself, but for some reason relying on a deprecated version of it (in the former case, you'd have to pester the plugin developer to update their own dependencies...);
- using PHP 7.2 or perhaps even a later version.

You *should* be using PHP 7.4 or 8.0 as of mid-2021 (everything else has been deprecated), so *your* installation is fine. It's just the obsolete code coming from that outdated version of Guzzle that requires updating.

So, a simple fix for that issue is to look at the culprit — open on your favourite editor the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php` and scroll down to line **67** (where the exception was thrown).

According to the trace you've posted, on that line you should have something like:

```php
if (count($some_variable_name_here) [...]) { [...] }
```

What happened, in this case, was the following:

- The `count()` function requires what PHP calls a [Countable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) object. Generally speaking, historically, these were arrays of some sort.
- Lazy programmers often use `count()` simply to check if the array is empty or not. In the pre-PHP7 days, `count(NULL)` was defined as being **0** or `false`, like so many other things in PHP. In other words: if the array was *either* empty (i.e. initialised but still without any item stored inside) *or* uninitialised (i.e. still assigned to `NULL`) *or* non-existent (i.e. a new variable which had not been declared before), then, by definition, `count(NULL)` was `false`.
- This allowed lazy programmers to check for a handful of potentially different error conditions with a single `if (!count($myArray)) { [...] do this; }`. In other words, you would just execute that code inside brackets *if* `$myArray` existed, was correctly initialised, and had at least one valid element. All that with a 'simple' check!
- Unfortunately, from the perspective of the interpreter and JIT compiler, as well as many other modern optimisation tools used by recent versions of PHP, this is terribly inefficient — besides being *very* sloppy programming. Starting with PHP 5.6, this misuse of `count()` became flagged as a warning, then later shown as a deprecated, and finally started throwing exceptions.
- So, in your case, whatever is on line 67, `count($some_variable_name_here)` has been passed an empty/invalid variable/array/object, and while this would be fine before PHP 7, it now throws an exception: `count()` will *not* work with so-called 'uncountable' objects, and for all purposes, an unexisting/empty/invalid object *is* uncountable *by definition*.

To *fix* it, all you need to do is to check *first* if the object *is* valid and not null, and *then* you can check if it has any elements inside it. In other words, instead of having something like:

```php
if (count($some_variable_name_here) [...]) {
  [... do something ...]
}
```

change it to:

```php
if (!empty($some_variable_name_here) && is_countable($some_variable_name_here) && count($some_variable_name_here) [...]) {
  [... do something ...]
}
```

Note that [`empty()` is a shortcut](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for `!isset($var) || $var == false`, and that PHP evaluates expressions from left to right, aborting as soon as a final result is known. If the variable is empty, the first check will immediately return `true` and the remaining checks will not even be called; by design, `empty()` does *not* throw an error or an exception and is safe to use in all scenarios where variables are in an 'unknown' state.

In many cases, you might get away just by checking if the object `$some_variable_name_here` is countable or not; a `NULL` object is not countable, so, it would also fail. In other cases — most frequent these days — you might not really know *what* has been passed: it might not be a valid, countable object. It might have more than one element, or zero. It might be just garbage and not properly initialised. Or any other possible combination. In those cases, being extra-careful with the checks (as opposed to being sloppy and relying upon PHP to do something useful with an otherwise useless variable/array/object) pays off.

Anyway, I've checked, and [the current version of Guzzle's `CurlFactory.php` still has a `count()` for function `release()`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php#L80), which is what is called before the exception is thrown. However, your own code is clearly different (at the time of writing, the current version has the `count()` on line 80, not 67), so it's very hard to say if you can correct it easily (there might be other, more subtle errors in the code calling `release()`...).

One assumes that Guzzle's latest version will fix these and other issues you might have — mostly because they *demand* PHP 7.2.5 or later, and that means that they have made changes to fix earlier things that didn't work as they should, and such changes were only possible with PHP 7.2.5.

Thus the recommendation is to upgrade your version of Guzzle. If there is any *good* reason to keep an outdated (and potentially bug-ridden and security-flawed) version around, well, now you know how to do a simple fix. At the very least, your code won't throw an exception; with luck, it will even work as you expect...

Happy hunting!